Calculating difference for columns SQL (automated or manual)
I have this data set:
CREATE TABLE #sample 
(
    sku nvarchar(max),
    data_type nvarchar(max),
    value_type nvarchar(max),
    value float
)

INSERT INTO #sample (sku,data_type,value_type,value)
VALUES ('sku1','forecast','units','100'),
       ('sku1','forecast','gross sales','40'),
       ('sku1','forecast','net sales','50'),
       ('sku1','forecast','gross profit','60'),
       ('sku1','actual','units','200'),
       ('sku1','actual','gross sales','80'),
       ('sku1','actual','net sales','30'),
       ('sku1','actual','gross profit','20');

As final report I need to show user the differences for each value type between actual and forecast. In the end I need separate column for each of calculated differences
here's an example of how it should look like:

The question is, should I do it manually by creating a diff column for each value type or there is an easier way?
Thank you!

Sample data is great, but a complete [mcve] is also supposed to specify the expected result.

@jarlh Thank you for comment, I edited my post & included final result

Show query, where you collecting data in one row.

You could use a self join based on the sku and value type, where one item in the join is used for the actual and the other for the forecast, and then subtract them:
SELECT a.sku, 
       a.value_type, 
       a.value AS actual_value,
       f.value AS forecast_value,
       a.value - f.value AS diff
FROM   #sample a
JOIN   #sample f ON a.data_type = 'actual' AND
                    f.data_type = 'forecast' AND
                    a.sku = f.sku AND
                    a.value_type = f.value_type

DBFiddle Demo

You could use conditional aggregation on joined forecast-actual data per sku:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table sample ( sku nvarchar(max), data_type nvarchar(max),
                      value_type nvarchar(max), value float )
Insert Into  sample ( sku, data_type, value_type, value ) 
VALUES ( 'sku1', 'forecast', 'units',        '100' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'forecast', 'gross sales',   '40' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'forecast', 'net sales',     '50' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'forecast', 'gross profit',  '60' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'actual',   'units',        '200' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'actual',   'gross sales',   '80' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'actual',   'net sales',     '30' ),
       ( 'sku1', 'actual',   'gross profit',  '20' );

--      S Q L : 
Select     a.sku, 
      Max( Case When a.value_type = 'units' Then a.value - f.value End ) as ACvsFC_units, 
      Max( Case When a.value_type = 'gross sales' Then a.value - f.value End ) as ACvsFC_gross_sales,
      Max( Case When a.value_type = 'net sales' Then a.value - f.value End ) as ACvsFC_net_sales,
      Max( Case When a.value_type = 'gross profit' Then a.value - f.value End ) as ACvsFC_gross_profit,
           --
      Max( Case When f.data_type = 'forecast' And f.value_type = 'units' 
                Then f.value 
           End ) as FC_units, 
      Max( Case When f.data_type = 'forecast' And f.value_type = 'gross sales' 
                Then f.value 
           End ) as FC_gross_sales,
      Max( Case When f.data_type = 'forecast' And f.value_type = 'net sales' 
                Then f.value 
           End ) as FC_net_sales,
      Max( Case When f.data_type = 'forecast' And f.value_type = 'gross profit' 
                Then f.value 
           End ) as FC_gross_profit,
           --
      Max( Case When a.data_type = 'actual' And a.value_type = 'units' 
                Then a.value 
           End ) as AC_units, 
      Max( Case When a.data_type = 'actual' And a.value_type = 'gross sales' 
                Then a.value 
           End ) as AC_gross_sales,
      Max( Case When a.data_type = 'actual' And a.value_type = 'net sales' 
                Then a.value 
           End ) as AC_net_sales,
      Max( Case When a.data_type = 'actual' And a.value_type = 'gross profit' 
                Then a.value 
           End ) as AC_gross_profit
From       sample a
Inner Join sample f ON( f.sku = a.sku And f.value_type = a.value_type )
Where      f.data_type = 'forecast' And
           a.data_type = 'actual' 
Group By   a.sku

/*        R e s u l t :
sku   ACvsFC_units  ACvsFC_gross_sales  ACvsFC_net_sales  ACvsFC_gross_profit  FC_units  FC_gross_sales  FC_net_sales  FC_gross_profit  AC_units  AC_gross_sales  AC_net_sales  AC_gross_profit
----  ------------  ------------------  ----------------  -------------------  --------  --------------  ------------  ---------------  --------  --------------  ------------  ---------------
sku1    100                         40               -20                  -40       100              40            50               60       200              80            30               20      */


See the fiddle here.
